# passing struct array to function for inputting value

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Need to pass a struct array to 2 functions so that the user can input the values.
This is the structure needed:

```c
struct Sale {
    double quantity;
    double unit_p;
    char taxable;
};
```

Calling the function in the main functions as:

```c
no_sales = enter(sales, MAX_SALES);
total(sales, no_sales);
```

and i am inputting values by:

```c
printf("Quantity    : ");
scanf("%lf", &s[i].quantity);   
printf("Unit Price  : ");
scanf("%lf", &s[i].unit_p);
printf("Taxable(y/n) : ");
scanf("%*c%c%*c", &s[i].taxable);
```

It compiles fine in gcc compiler.  When I ran the program I can enter the values but when I try to print the values it displays all values as 0. The values are not being stored in struct array

output I am getting:

```
Quantity    : 2
Unit Price  : 1.99
Taxable(y/n) : y

Quantity Unit Price
0.000000  0.000000
```

The whole code:
program accepts the values and calculates total price in 2 separate functions

```c
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX_SALES = 10;

struct Sale {
    double quantity;
    double unit_p;
    char taxable;
};

void total(const struct Sale *s,int n);
int enter(struct Sale *s, int M);

int main()
{
    int no_sales;
    struct Sale sales[MAX_SALES];
    printf("Sale Records \n");
    printf("=============\n");
    no_sales = enter(sales, MAX_SALES);
    total(sales, no_sales);
}

int enter(struct Sale *s, int M)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("Quantity    : ");
    scanf("%lf", &s[i].quantity);
    while(s[i].quantity != 0) {
        printf("Unit Price  : ");
        scanf("%lf", &s[i].unit_p);
        printf("Taxable(y/n) : ");
        scanf("%*c%c%*c", &s[i].taxable);
        i++;
        if(i == M) {
            printf("Maximum exceeded\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("Quantity    : ");
        scanf("%lf", &s[i].quantity);
    }

    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("%lf %lf %c\n", s[i].quantity, s[i].unit_p, s[i].taxable);
    }

    return i;
}

void total(const struct Sale *s,int n)
{
    int i, subtot = 0, hst = 0, tot = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        subtot = subtot + (s[i].quantity * s[i].unit_p);
        if(s[i].taxable == 'y' || s[i].taxable == 'Y') {
            hst = hst + (0.13 * s[i].quantity * s[i].unit_p);
        }
    }
    tot = subtot + hst;
    printf("\n%-12s%.2lf", "Subtotal", subtot);
    printf("\n%-12s%.2lf", "HST (13%)", hst);
    printf("\n%-12s%.2lf\n", "Total", tot);
}
```

Comment: How do you print them? Show the code that prints the variables. Also add the definition of your structure.

Comment: How are you creating an array of `Sale`?

Comment: For the moment, I see something wrong in your last scanf(). It is using a format that asks for several variables, even... field delimiters?

Comment: the last scanf is accepting a character so i want to discard the data in input buffer that is why i use 2 %*c

Comment: .i am able to enter values but it is not being saved to the array. what is the proper way to pass struct array by reference?

Answer (score 0):

In function `enter()` you are using the wrong index variable `i` to access the struct:

```c
for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    printf("%lf %lf %c\n", s[i].quantity, s[i].unit_p, s[i].taxable);
}
```

which should be

```c
for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    printf("%lf %lf %c\n", s[j].quantity, s[j].unit_p, s[j].taxable);
}
```

Second, in function `total()`, your variables for calculating the totals, should be of type `double`

```c
int i;
double subtot = 0, hst = 0, tot = 0;
...
```